# Deploying Custom Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, kubectl

I have made some custom changes to `k8s.io/kubernetes/kubernetes`, specifically in the `pkg/controllers` to support some functionality of a project i’m working on. What is the canonical way to deploy & test these changes? Is there like an optional in kubectl to use a custom image of kubernetes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ton of documentation. Try: https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/testing.md

kubectl just talks to what it hopes is an API service. kubectl and the various server bits are versioned independently, and there are documented expectations for cross-version interoperability.